# How to prevent scroll parent element even if the child is not scrollable?

Tags: html, css

Using CSS property `ovescroll-bahavior`, we can prevent scrolling the parent element when the inner element reaches the top or bottom. But when there is too little content in the child to be scrollable, The parent is scrolled instead. I would like no scrolling to happen in this case for consistency. How can I achieve this?

```css
.child {
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  margin: 1em;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
}

.parent {
  height: 8em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  If you try to scroll the first box, the outer box should never be scrolled. But if you try to scroll the second box, the outer box is scrolled, which is undesired.
  <div class="child">
    1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    1<br>2<br>3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "If you try to scroll the first box, the outer box should never be scrolled. But if you try to scroll the second box, the outer box is scrolled, which is undesired." is it just me or running the code snippet doesn't show that behaviour?

Comment: @user_ in order for the `overscroll-behavior-y` to work as expected in the `child` the `child` will need to be scrollable. Otherwise, you will need JS.

Comment: @user_ Which behavior exactly did you not observe?

Comment: @user please, don't mind my comment, I realized I can't answer this, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, in order for `overscroll-behavior-y` to work as expected the `child` needs to be scrollable. An option would be to use a `span` element with a [`&nbsp;`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp#:%7E:text=A%20commonly%20used%20entity%20in,the%20words%20might%20be%20disruptive.) Finally, just add a `max-height` on this new `span` so that `overflow` is generated. Ultimately leading to the `overscroll-behavior-y` to work as desired.

```css
.child {
  max-height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  margin: 1em;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
}

.parent {
  max-height: 8em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: solid;
}

span {
  display: block;
  max-height: 3.5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  If you try to scroll the first box, the outer box should never be scrolled. But if you try to scroll the second box, the outer box is scrolled, which is undesired.
  <div class="child">
    1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    1<br>2<br>3<br>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a workaround, not a solution. It is awkward to have unnecessary scroll.

Comment: @user Well, as I mentioned, it is not possible because it would have to have overflow (scroll) in order for `overscroll-behavior-y` to work. So like I said you would have to use JS. A CSS solution would be to make it so the ones with scroll always have a scrollbar displayed using `::-webkit-scrollbar` so it's easily noticeable which ones have scroll and which do not.

Comment: @user like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/bmn32xkL/1/).